# How Can I Determine the Size of the 'My Documents' Folder for every user on a local machine using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I am at my wits end into this. Either I am doing it the wrong way or it is not possible.

I need a vb script for the following scenario:

1. The script is to run on multiple Windows 7 machines (32-Bit & 64-Bit alike).
2. These are shared workstation i.e. different users login to these machines from time to time.
3. The objective of this script is to **traverse through each User Profile folder** and get the **size of the 'My Documents' folder within each User Profile folder**. This information is to be written to a .CSV file located at C:\Temp directory on the machine.
4. This script would be pushed to all workstations from SCCM. It would be configured to execute with System Rights

I tried the script detailed at:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/03/31/how-can-i-determine-the-size-of-the-my-documents-folder.aspx

```
Const MY_DOCUMENTS = &H5&

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(MY_DOCUMENTS)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
strPath = objFolderItem.Path

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)
Wscript.Echo objFolder.Size
```

The **Wscript.Echo objFolder.Size** command in the script returned the value as '0' (zero) for the current logged on user. Although the actual size was like 30 MB or so.

I then tried the script at:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/VB_Script/Q_27869829.html

This script returns the correct value but only for the current logged-on user.

```
Const blnShowErrors = False

' Set up filesystem object for usage
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Display desired folder sizes
Wscript.Echo "MyDocuments : " & FormatSize(FindFiles(objFSO.GetFolder(objShell.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments"))))


' Recursively tally the size of all files under a folder
' Protect against folders or files that are not accessible
Function FindFiles(objFolder)
   On Error Resume Next

   ' List files
   For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
       On Error Resume Next
       If Err.Number <> 0 Then ShowError "FindFiles:01", objFolder.Path
       On Error Resume Next
       FindFiles = FindFiles + objFile.Size
       If Err.Number <> 0 Then ShowError "FindFiles:02", objFile.Path
   Next

   If Err.Number = 0 Then
       ' Recursively drill down into subfolder
       For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
           On Error Resume Next
           If Err.Number <> 0 Then ShowError "FindFiles:04", objFolder.Path
           FindFiles = FindFiles + FindFiles(objSubFolder)
           If Err.Number <> 0 Then ShowError "FindFiles:05", objSubFolder.Path
       Next
   Else
       ShowError "FindFiles:03", objFolder.Path
   End If
End Function

' Function to format a number into typical size scales
Function FormatSize(iSize)
   aLabel = Array("bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB")
   For i = 0 to 4
      If iSize > 1024 Then iSize = iSize / 1024 Else Exit For End If
   Next
   FormatSize = Round(iSize, 2) & " " & aLabel(i)
End Function

Sub ShowError(strLocation, strMessage)
   If blnShowErrors Then
      WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "==> ERROR at [" & strLocation & "]"
      WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "    Number:[" & Err.Number & "], Source:[" & Err.Source & "], Desc:[" &  Err.Description & "]"
      WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "    " & strMessage
      Err.Clear
   End If
End Sub
```

The only part pending, is to achieve this for the **'My Documents'** folder within each of the other User Profile folders.

Is this possible?

Please help.

Comment: I suspect the problem will be with permissions. Windows 7 is like that... try to do something like `fso.GetFolder("C:\users\[blah]\Documents").Size` on each folder in C:\users and you're likely to get an access denied error on each.